# Does Python's `tarfile` module store the archives it's building in memory?

Tags: python, memory, tar, tarfile

I'm working in a memory constrained environment where I need to make archives of SQL dumps. If I use python's built in [`tarfile` module](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) is the '.tar' file held in memory or written to disk as it's created?

For instance, in the following code, if `huge_file.sql` is 2GB will the `tar` variable take up 2GB in memory?

```
import tarfile

tar = tarfile.open("my_archive.tar.gz")), "w|gz")
tar.add('huge_file.sql')
tar.close()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not loading it in memory. You can read the [source for tarfile](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/default/Lib/tarfile.py) to see that it's using `copyfileobj`, which is using a fixed size buffer to copy from the file to the tarball:

```
def copyfileobj(src, dst, length=None):
    """Copy length bytes from fileobj src to fileobj dst.
       If length is None, copy the entire content.
    """
    if length == 0:
        return
    if length is None:
        shutil.copyfileobj(src, dst)
        return

    BUFSIZE = 16 * 1024
    blocks, remainder = divmod(length, BUFSIZE)
    for b in xrange(blocks):
        buf = src.read(BUFSIZE)
        if len(buf) < BUFSIZE:
            raise IOError("end of file reached")
        dst.write(buf)

    if remainder != 0:
        buf = src.read(remainder)
        if len(buf) < remainder:
            raise IOError("end of file reached")
        dst.write(buf)
    return
```

Comment: +1 for linking to the source. Development docs now also have a link to sources http://docs.python.org/dev/library/tarfile